# Indenting bullet within `fbox`

Tags: itemize, minipage

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt] {article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


\begin{document}
Previous text
  \fbox{
       \noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
           \begin{itemize}
               \item \textbf{Note:-}  I want this.
           \end{itemize}
       \end{minipage}
   }
Next text
\end{document}
```

With this, the indention of the text with the bullet moves towards right side. How do I move the text to the left side of the page? Also the gaps on the top and bottom of the box seem lesser than regular height.